# Pin Tool unexpected instrumentation result

Tags: dbi, instrumentation

I've got very unexpected result from Pin Tool, my tool looks for CALL/RET instructions and then log the proper message :

```
VOID CallBack(VOID * ip, ADDRINT esp)
{
    UINT32 *RetAddrPtr = (UINT32 *)esp;
    fprintf(log_info,"RET inst @%p ==> Retuen Address @%p.\n", ip, *RetAddrPtr);
}

// Pin calls this function every time a new instruction is encountered
VOID Trace(TRACE trace, VOID *v)
{
    ADDRINT insAddress = TRACE_Address(trace);

    // Visit every basic block in the trace
    for (BBL bbl = TRACE_BblHead(trace); BBL_Valid(bbl); bbl = BBL_Next(bbl))
    {
        for(INS ins = BBL_InsHead(bbl); INS_Valid(ins); ins = INS_Next(ins))
        {   
            ADDRINT instAddress = INS_Address(ins);

            if( INS_IsCall(ins) )
            {
                ADDRINT nextInstAddress = (ADDRINT)( (USIZE)instAddress + INS_Size(ins) );
                fprintf(log_info,"CALL  inst @%p    ==> CALL Return Address @%p.\n", instAddress, nextInstAddress);
            }  
            if(INS_IsRet(ins))
            {
                INS_InsertCall( ins, 
                                IPOINT_BEFORE, 
                                (AFUNPTR)CallBack, 
                                IARG_INST_PTR, 
                                IARG_REG_VALUE, 
                                REG_STACK_PTR, 
                                IARG_END);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the result is very unusual :-/. see this is log result from program entry point:

```
CALL    inst @0101247C  ==> CALL Return Address @01012481.
RET inst @01012800 ==> Return Address @01012481.
CALL    inst @0101248A  ==> CALL Return Address @0101248C.
CALL    inst @7C80B73F  ==> CALL Return Address @7C80B744.
RET inst @7C80B751 ==> Return Address @0101248C.
CALL    inst @010124E3  ==> CALL Return Address @010124E9.
RET inst @77C3538A ==> Return Address @010124E9.
CALL    inst @010124F8  ==> CALL Return Address @010124FE.
RET inst @77C1F1E0 ==> Return Address @010124FE.
CALL    inst @01012506  ==> CALL Return Address @0101250C.
RET inst @77C1F1A9 ==> Return Address @0101250C.
CALL    inst @01012520  ==> CALL Return Address @01012525.
RET inst @010127C4 ==> Return Address @01012525.
CALL    inst @01012532  ==> CALL Return Address @01012538.
CALL    inst @01012539  ==> CALL Return Address @0101253E.
CALL    inst @010127BA  ==> CALL Return Address @010127BF.
CALL    inst @77C4EE60  ==> CALL Return Address @77C4EE65.
RET inst @77C4ED04 ==> Return Address @77C4EE28. <=========
RET inst @77C4ED97 ==> Return Address @77C4EE3F. <=========
RET inst @77C4EE49 ==> Return Address @77C4EE65.
RET inst @77C4EE68 ==> Return Address @010127BF.
RET inst @010127C1 ==> Return Address @0101253E.
```

as you can see, there is two RET instruction which doesn't map to any CALL.
after this I opened up program in debugger and saw this :

```
77C4EE15 >  8BFF            MOV EDI,EDI                              ; kernel32.GetModuleHandleA
77C4EE17    55              PUSH EBP
77C4EE18    8BEC            MOV EBP,ESP
77C4EE1A    51              PUSH ECX
77C4EE1B    53              PUSH EBX
77C4EE1C    9B              WAIT
77C4EE1D    D97D FC         FSTCW WORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
77C4EE20    FF75 FC         PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
77C4EE23    E8 41FEFFFF     CALL msvcrt.77C4EC69 <============
77C4EE28    8BD8            MOV EBX,EAX
77C4EE2A    8B45 0C         MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]
77C4EE2D    F7D0            NOT EAX
77C4EE2F    23D8            AND EBX,EAX
77C4EE31    8B45 08         MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
77C4EE34    2345 0C         AND EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]
77C4EE37    59              POP ECX                                  ; msvcrt.77C4EE65
77C4EE38    0BD8            OR EBX,EAX
77C4EE3A    E8 CBFEFFFF     CALL msvcrt.77C4ED0A <==============
77C4EE3F    8945 0C         MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C],EAX
77C4EE42    D96D 0C         FLDCW WORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]
77C4EE45    8BC3            MOV EAX,EBX
77C4EE47    5B              POP EBX                                  ; msvcrt.77C4EE65
77C4EE48    C9              LEAVE
```

Pin Tool cannot see this calls ? I think maybe I used a wrong sequence of API call.
and also there is another unexpected result: there is two different CALL instructions within a function with a conditional jmp between CALLs, which means just of those CALL instructions should execute but Pin log both of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pin doesn't instrument ALL the process execution, it starts it a little bit after the real process start and ends a little bit before the real exit.
The call was probably executed when process execution wasn't redirected to Pin yet this is why you see the retn and not the call.

a little piece of code to explain it :

```
call start_instrumentation  
label ret_call_start_ins:  
[...]

function start_instrumentation:

_do_stuff_  
* now the process is under Pin control *  
_do_stuff_under_pin_control_  

retn ; the return you see without any associated call
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this result is logged by my pin tool dll.you see Pin spot "CALL inst @77C4EE60" ,this will call sub_77C4EE15 ( you can see sub_77C4EE15 codes in my question ) and inside this function is two other CALLs which Pin cant detect! this is what I mean unexpected. why Pin cant detect those CALLs inside sub_77C4EE15 while it's instrumentation is early begin.

Comment: spotting calls don't mean they will be executed. You should add an INS_InsertCall to be sure they are. maybe 77C4EE60 is never called and so 77C4EE15 neither

Comment: very thanks Baboon, adding INS_InsertCall solved my problem :)